# Getting Production data for iOS apps with Testflight sdk

Tags: ios, testflight

I have an iOS App with Testflight's sdk 1.1 enabled to get production data. This worked well during beta testing and I submitted the same build (with sdk enabled) to Appstore and the build is approved and released. 
However, I dont see any data regarding the usage in testflight live. I have been looking around to find if there are any special setup needed for that without success.

Note that I DONT have the same build version as in appstore in testflight anymore. But I figured that testflight live will still be able to show usage dat.

Anyone have experience with this? Can someone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking around, it looks like as of v1.1, you NEED to have the same build that is submitted to Appstore to be in testflight as well. The reason is that the event matching is done using the UUID of the build. 
Their support indicated that they are working on handling orphaned build events as well.

Comment: rydgaze, thank you for pointing that out. I am currently having the same problem, I was unable to resolve it by uploading the exact same release build to testfligh though. Could you please provide the link or source where you found the info regarding event matching? Maybe there's something else I've been missing...

Comment: Their support response:
This is what I got "The way this currently works is that the production build needs to have the TestFlight SDK. It also needs to have been uploaded to TestFlight.

The standard workflow was to build an adhoc, beta test it with TestFlight. Resign the build for production, submit to Apple. Then the production data starts to show up on TF live. Both the Appstore version and Ad Hoc version need to be exactly the same, sans profile signing. 

We definitely realize this isn't everyones workflow and we will be working on making "orphaned" build data accessible throu.. <snip>"